# How to fix 'constructor is invalid use' in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm want to print "name,id, age, cpp_score, cpp_count". When I use constructor in "main()", Dev c++ will show this error "invalid use of 'Student::Student'".

```
    Student(string name,int age,int id,  float cpp_score, float cpp_count):Person(name, age){
        this->name = name;
        this->id = id;
        this->age = age;
        this->cpp_score = cpp_score;
        this->cpp_count = cpp_count; 
    }



Student *stu[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
    cin >> name>>id>>age>>cpp_score >> cpp_count;
    stu[i]= new Student(name,age,id,  cpp_score, cpp_count);
};
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: use actual code instead of images

Comment: Sorry, I want to do this. but code show incomplete, and a small amount of code don't describe my question. I will reflect and correct :) Thinks you.

Comment: @SugarKeek just cop-paste the code of the 2 classes and your main, exactly as it is on the screenshot.  We don't need the rest.

Comment: OK, I have learned it.

Comment: Welcome to SO Please take your time to apply proper tags to your question. Your question is not related to C but C++. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: sorry, at the very start, I choose C++, but I don't know why, it change C from C++, I will draw a distinction between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Student` is not a function that can be called on a `Student*` pointer. To construct an object call `new Student`.

```
stu[i] = new Student(Name, id, age, cpp_score, cpp_count);
```

Or even better: don't use raw pointers, use a `std::vector<Student>`. Compare the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) for that.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> stu[i]->Student(...)
> ```

must be

```
stu[i] = new Student(...):
```